ROSE package in R not reading variable correctly; does not read updated value contained in variable
I'm hoping to receive some help here as I've struggled for a while now and I cannot figure out the problem.
I am using the ROSE package in R, attempting to make use of the function for random over/undersampling ovun.sample. Here is a description for the function for any wanting to read about how it works and what input it takes:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ROSE/versions/0.0-4/topics/ovun.sample
I am calculating a value for N and then plugging it into ovun.sample, all done inside another a function. While the calculated value for N is correct and would yield the correct imbalance ratio, the function doesn't seem to recognize the value, and produces this error:
Error in N < n : 
  comparison (<) is possible only for atomic and list types

I have tried multiple angles to try and figure out the issue, to no avail. From what I have surmised, the issue is that ovun.sample is reading n as the global variable n, which does not exist. When I print out the calculated n instead and paste the integer value into ovun.sample it works perfectly.
It is a bit of a long explanation as to why this is wrapped in another function, but this is part of a much larger project and it is designed this way to save a lot of time down the line and avoid too many nested loops and unnecessary code. I do acknowledge that removing it from the function would probably fix the issue but it should be considered not an option to remove it.
I also tried using the p argument in ovun.sample, which worked as expected. The issue was that is was more difficult to yield the expected imbalance ratio using this avenue. But in this case, I also calculated what p should be inside the function, and input the value as I tried with N.
I hope someone can make sense of this, apologies if my explanation is unclear - please let me know if there is anything I should clarify.
Here is the relevant code with a reproducible example:
library("ROSE")

data(hacide)

ros = function(data, im_ratio) {
  num_zero = sum(data$cls == 0)
  n = round(num_zero *im_ratio) + num_zero 
  print(n)
  rebalanced = ovun.sample(cls ~ ., data=data, 
                           method="over", N=n)$data
  return(rebalanced)
}

over_sample = ros(hacide.train, 0.4)
over_sample



For those with the same issue and looking for a quick fix - I got around the problem by declaring global variables inside the function, which means they'd be stored and updated in the event of using the function again.
I did this by changing the = to <<-, so the line is now: n <<- round(num_zero *im_ratio) + num_zero.
Not the most elegant, but gets the job done.
